# State Pattern: States as Hibernate singleton entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, design-patterns

***What I have:***
I've implemnted a `State Pattern. Now I have a dozen of States in my app, all of them are Spring's beans, like:

```
@Service(value = "FinishedState")
@Scope("singleton")
public class FinishedState extends AbstractState {    
  private final String stateName = "Finished";
  private final String badgeColor = "#459852";

  //implementation of state API
}
```

***What I want:***
Be able to change `stateName` and `badgeColor` without recompiling my application. Or in other words I want to store my states in DB.

***What a question:***

1. *Is it good idea to make all States as Singleton entities?*
2. *What diffculties may I face?*

Means that I will manually set an id to each State , like  `id = this.getClass().getSimpleName()`, and map all state-siblings into one table.

---

***Edit (for @Adam Arold):***

And also its worth to say that I *need that other entities can reference that Singleton's states*.

```
@Service(value = "FinishedState ")
@Scope("singleton")
public class FinishedState extends AbstractState {
  private final String stateName = "Finished";
  private final String badgeColor = "#459852";

  @Override
  public void someMethod1(Session session, String newState, MyEntity entity) {
       entity.setStatus(newState);
       writeHistory(entity);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean someMethod2(Session session, AbstractState newState, MyEntity entity) 
  {
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the state implementation?

Comment: @Adam Arold, see EDIT section of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "state")
public class StateBase {

    /**
     * Entity API
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); //prevent from creating two instances of state

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "badgeColor")
    private String badgeColor;

    //only Getters! also hashCode and Equals
    //.....................

    /**
     * ======== State API ========
     * Use TEMPLATE METHOD and hooks
     */
    final public void changeState(Session session, State newState, StateEntity entity) { //StateEntity is interface that is implemented by all entities that have a state
        if(newState.equals(this)) return;

        if (canMove(session, newState, entity)) {
            hook(session, newState, entity);
            beforeTransition(session, newState, entity);
            makeTransition(session, newState, entity);
            afterTransition(session, newState, entity);
        } else {
            throw new TransitionDeniedException("Transition from " + getName() + " to " + newState.getName() + " is denied.");
        }
    }

    //Defauls implementation for all (or almost all hooks)
    protected void beforeTransition(Session session, State newState, StateEntity entity) {
        entity.setState(newState);
    }

    protected void afterTransition(Session session, State newState, StateEntity entity) {
        writeHistory(entity);
       session.merge(entity);
    }
    //..........................
}
```

And than:

```
@Entity
public class SpecificState extends StateBase {

    //Override hook
    @Override
    public void makeTransition(Session session, State newState, StateEntity entity) {
        MyEntity myEntity = (MyEntity ) entity;
        String commentText = "some comment";
        String author = "[autogenerated]";
        addProfileComment(session, myEntity, commentText, author);
    }
}
```

Due to my implementation, all states are entites, but they have only private String field without Setters. So they have no muttable state. So it isn't realy matter if there can exist one or more entities of specific state (in memory). In DB I can store only one entity of specific state class at once.

*Advantages*

1. It's allow me to forget about troubles of state synchronization and another possible difficulties linked with replacement of Spring singleton beans with Hibernate entities.
2. It's also allows user to change `name` and `badgeColor` through admin tool without recompiling the whole application.

*Disadvantages:*

Not observed.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I make my states Singletons is when I am changing states frequently. This is useful when performance is essential -- in the case that I do not wish to call `new` every time I switch back and forth from states.

**Suggestion**

My suggestion to you is that you analyze:

- How does your system operate in regards to the states?
- Do you change states frequently?
- Can you afford the space in memory of having a bunch of instances of
  states alive during the execution of the system?

The only issue I see that you can come across is that while your system is running the Singleton states will be alive until the system finishes.

Personally
**I would make them Singletons though**