# Hibernate: entity class name as identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

**I want to make my entity a singleton. That singleton should be accessible from other entities.**

So I decide to set its id manyally, like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableName")
public class SingletonEntity {

  @Id
  private int id = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); //IS IT POSSIBLE? HOW?

  //.......
}
```

***Question:***

*How to achieve that?* Please. give me an example.

***EDIT:***

It is worth to say that my `SingletonEntity` has only final string state. So I can say that its stateless. Actually, I don't want a singleton, I only want to set final id to that entity, and I want that id should be equals to `SingletonEntity.class.getSimpleName()`

***For @Balaji Reddy:***

I've tried:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private static final String id = Client.class.getSimpleName();

    .................
}
```

And get:

> No identifier specified for entity: db.Client

in string

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: @Alberto Solano, yes I've read ). I've implemented a `State Pattern`. Each of my states is a singleton. I can make them a spring beans, but there is a little problem. Each of those states has it own state (final in my case). So if I make them a spring beans I need to recompiling my app each time I want to change their state. I see the solution in making them a singleton entities. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091168/state-pattern-states-as-hibernate-singleton-entities

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are asking. Perhaps you should take a look at IOC frameworks that manage singletons way better than manually done with static fields / functions. I think you should change your question about: initialization of field of entity by the class simple name.

Comment: I have Spring's singleton beans. I look for correct way to replace those beans with hibernate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using a constant?

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = SingletonEntity.class.getSimpleName();

@Id
private String id = CLASS_NAME;
```

This is the initialization of the field of your entity, you can also do this in the constructor.

```
private SingletonEntity() {
    this.id = this.getClass.getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: @NickoleAbs for the same id, the same columns will be updated in your datastore, if it is not the case check your mapping + database. You should not worry about that, primary keys are by definition unique. Maybe you are looking for disabling rewriting of an existing entity which is a different case.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableName")
public class SingletonEntity {

  @Id
  private static int id = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); //try something like this.

  //.......
}
```

Check [EJB Specifications 3.1](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363656/New-Features-in-EJB-31)

Comment: Does it work for you? I can try only after a large refactoring; just want to be certain about that. And what about final? I want to be certain that noone can store in DB two entities of one class .

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Look at 'For @Balaji Reddy' section of my question